# Not able to update channel type in aws pinpoint

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-pinpoint

I have just started to use the AWS pinpoint, and I was trying to update the channelType in with the updatePinpoint call, but it is not using the provided value in the code, and setting it to by default to **APNS**,

The same issue is happening with the location and some other fields.

```
Analytics.updateEndpoint({
    Address: user.email,
    Attributes: {
      userProfile: [user.companyId]
    },
    ChannelType: 'EMAIL',
    UserId: user.pid,
    UserAttributes: {
      role: userRoles
    },
    Location: { City: 'Gandhinagar' }
  });
```

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue with the format of your call in regards to the user data. It should look like this:

```
Analytics.updateEndpoint({
  Address: user.email,
  Attributes: {
      userProfile: [user.companyId]
  },
  ChannelType: 'EMAIL',
  User: {
    UserId: user.pid,
    UserAttributes: {
       role: userRoles
    }
  },
  Location: {
    City: 'Gandhinagar'
  }
});
```

You probably also want to hook up the callback and inspect the error handler so that you can see if the call goes wrong (Which would have shown your issue).